# Segmentation Fault on GPU tests for new MSI GeForce GTX 1060

Tags: linux, memory, debian, graphics-card, gpu

I purchased a new MSI 6GB GeForce GTX 1060 recently, and I am running Debian Linux (8.0 - stable). I installed the proprietary nVidia drivers (version 367 from jessie-backports) and the nvidia-cuda-toolkit (also from jessie-backports). I then tried running the Unigine Heaven benchmark. I get to the initial screen, and hit "Run", and right after it finishes loading it crashes. The CLI displays the following error:

> Received signal SIGSEGV, invalid memory reference

The Unigine Valley benchmarks fails similarly. This got me concerned, so I tried to test it out with [memtestG80](https://simtk.org/home/memtest), this also failed with a single line: `Segmentation fault`.

I've been able to run [these stress tests](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/) without issue.

Does this indicate that there really is a problem with the GPU memory, or is something else possibly the culprit?

Comment: try latest Debian 8.6 https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/iso-cd/

Comment: I am using the latest up-to-date Debian. (Shouldn't have said 8.0 specifically, just meant major version 8)

Comment: boot the Win10 trial edition from a usb drive (WinToGo) and do some tests with benchmark tool and look if the GPU works fine. if you also get crashes, the GPU may have issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 that was an excellent suggestion, which unfortunately ended with a resounding - huh? MemtestG80 indicated all sorts of errors, even only testing 1024 MB of RAM, but then I noticed it is from ~2010, and may not work anymore (it crashed immediately when trying to test 6GB, for example). MSI's Kombustor has a FurMark Stress Test which claims to have tested 5374MB of the RAM, and it didn't report any errors (though I'm not sure it would have). I ran a similar test from EVGA and it reported "0 artifacts" while running, but unlike the MSI tests nothing was moving during the test...

Comment: try windows memtest that is part of win10 or use a newer memtest86+ version: http://www.memtest.org/#downiso

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I don't think any of those test the GPU RAM, which is what I'm after. Are you saying that you suspect the regular RAM is faulty?

Comment: normal RAM may also cause it. For VRAM, I know this (windows) tool: http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en

Comment: try the latest 8.7: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.7.0/amd64/iso-dvd/